# Подскажите, как лямбда берет свое значение?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

```
def mutliplyer(x):             # умножитель - возвращает функцию "умножить на x"
    return lambda y: x*y
    
foo=mutliplyer(3)     # умножитель на 3
bar=mutliplyer(-7)    # умножитель на -7
 
print(foo(3))  # 9
print(bar(8))  # -56
```

Comment: `foo=mutliplyer(3)` => `foo = lambda y: 3*y`

Comment: почему значение перешло в лямбдо функцию если присвоили мы обычную?

Comment: @krokoboy присвоить обычную это `foo=mutliplyer` а `foo=mutliplyer(3)` - присваивание результата вызова функции, а в результате `лямбда`

Comment: все, я понял, спасибо!!!